# NSScrollView does not scroll

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

I am attempting to implement an NSScollview for a Mac app.  I have created a simple test app.  In the IB, I just create a view controller with its view set to an NSScrollview.

In the viewDidLoad, I have just this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSImage * image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"harley-davidson-electra-glide-6"];

    NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    imageView.image = image;

    [self.scrollView setDocumentView:imageView];
}
```

Note that the image size is: `(width = 1920, height = 1200)`

When I run this I get a window which shows just a small portion of the image.  For a half-second, a horizontal scrollbar appears, then disappears; however, there is no scrolling capability.  I can click and drag anywhere in the window and nothing happens.

Answer (score -2):

I would try to add the `contentSize` to the NSScrollView object:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/contentSize